# Is it possible to call an indicator in the strategy?

Tags: pine-script, indicator, pine-script-v5

I wrote an indicator and called higher time frames in it. Now how can I use this indicator in my strategy? Can the indicator be called in the strategy?

Comment: An indicator plot can be transferred as the input value for `input.source(...)` in a strategy.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.